# HAML: Got "elsif" with no preceding "if"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I need this construction in my HAML code:

```
- if @organisation.type == 'Company'
%p
  %strong Number of Employees:
  = @organisation.number_of_employees
- elsif @organisation.type == 'EducationalInstitution'
%p
  %strong Number of Students
  = @organisation.number_of_students
```

But i get an Syntax error:  Got "elsif" with no preceding "if"
How I must to update my code to solve the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your indentation looks like it might be the issue

```
- if @organisation.type == 'Company'
  %p
    %strong Number of Employees:
    = @organisation.number_of_employees
- elsif @organisation.type == 'EducationalInstitution'
  %p
    %strong Number of Students
    = @organisation.number_of_students
```

### Bonus indenting quirk

The if/else statement to fail if commenting does not also adhere to the correct indentation.

e.g.

```
- if @organisation.type == 'Company'
  %p
    %strong Number of Employees:
    = @organisation.number_of_employees

-# Institutional case
- elsif @organisation.type == 'EducationalInstitution'
  %p
    %strong Number of Students
    = @organisation.number_of_students
```

will fail. Where

```
- if @organisation.type == 'Company'
  %p
    %strong Number of Employees:
    = @organisation.number_of_employees

- elsif @organisation.type == 'EducationalInstitution'
  -# Institutional case
  %p
    %strong Number of Students
    = @organisation.number_of_students
```

will is correct.

Comment: you're very welcome.. did that solve the issue? `:)`

Comment: excellent.. glad to hear it.   go ahead and click the Green checkmark so this question can close